# Compute $\frac{f(i\frac{\pi}{2})}{f(i\pi)}$ for an analytic function.

Tags: complex-analysis

I came across this problem and I'm having a little trouble.

Let $f$ : $\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a nonconstant analytic function. Assume that on $\mathbb{R}$ the function is **real-valued** and **equal to its own derivative**, then compute $\frac{f(i\frac{\pi}{2})}{f(i\pi)}$.

My attempt:
Assume $f(x,y) = u(x,y) + iv(x,y)$, then $v(x,y) = 0$ for a real-valued function. Then as a consequence of the Cauchy-Riemann Equations, $f'(x,y) = u_x + i v_x = u_x$, which then means $f(x,y) = u= u_x$ since $f(x,y) = f'(x,y)$. However, isn't $u_x = 0$, since $f$ is analytic and $u_x = v_y$?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f'(x) = f(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$ then
$f'(z) = f(z)$ for all $z \in \mathbb C$ ([Identity Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem)).

If follows that the derivative of $g(z):= f(z)e^{-z}$ is identically
to zero so that $g$ is a constant and
$$
  f(z) = C e^z \text{ for some } C \in \mathbb C \, .
$$
$C$ is not zero because $f$ is assumed to be non-constant.
(If $f$ is real-valued on $\mathbb R$ then $C = f(0) \in \mathbb R$,
but that is actually not needed to compute the result.)

Now you can evaluate $\dfrac{f(i\frac{\pi}{2})}{f(i\pi)}$.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, my misunderstanding was just a misreading. I missed that the function is assumed real-valued only on $\mathbb{R}$.